# MVC2/Jquery validation issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

I have read the following:
http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/08/23/asp-net-mvc-jquery-validation-and-validationsummary.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx

And still can't get the jQuery validation to work with MVC2.  I can get non jQuery working but when i swap out the JS files it doesn't work.  It's going on day 3 and I'm totally stuck at this point. So here is what I have.  I appreciate your help.

Site.Master

```
 <script src="<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Resources/js/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Resources/js/jquery.validate.js") %>"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Resources/js/MicrosoftMvcJqueryValidation.js") %>"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Resources/js/ourJS--VERSION--.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Resources/js/json2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../Resources/css/ourCSS--VERSION--.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace OurNamespace
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public class OurDataModelView : PersistedDataModelView
    {
        public OurModelView () : base()
        {
            ID = -1;
            StartDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            EndDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            Description = string.Empty;
            Deleted = false;
        }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Description is required.")]
        [StringLength(250000, ErrorMessage = "A maximum of 250000 characters are allowed")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int? ID { get; set; }

        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ASPX page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
...
 <% Html.RenderAction(WebConstants.ACTION_DISPLAY_HEADER, WebConstants.CONTROLLER, new { id = ViewData["ID"] }); %>
...
```

our partial view that validation is done on:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<OurNameSpace.OurDataModelView>" %>
...
        <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
        <% using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post , new { id = "HeaderForm", onSubmit="return false;"})) { %>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(false, "validation failed") %>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID) %>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-label">Description</div>
            <div class="form-element"><%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description)%></div>
            <div><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description) %></div>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <input id="Save" type="submit" class="save-button" value="" />
            <div id="Cancel" class="cancel-button"></div>
        </div>

        <% } %>
...
```

****SO by doesn't work here is what I do see.
on view source I see:

```
//<![CDATA[
if (!window.mvcClientValidationMetadata) { window.mvcClientValidationMetadata = []; }
window.mvcClientValidationMetadata.push({"Fields":[{"FieldName":"Description","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"Description_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"A maximum of 250000 characters are allowed","ValidationParameters":{"minimumLength":0,"maximumLength":250000},"ValidationType":"stringLength"},{"ErrorMessage":"Description is required.","ValidationParameters":{},"ValidationType":"required"}]}],"FormId":"HeaderForm","ReplaceValidationSummary":true,"ValidationSummaryId":"validationSummary"});
//]]>
```

However, client side validation is not appearing.  I click on the textarea type in a char and delete it unfocus from the element and nothing happens.  Any ideas for debugging this?

Comment: I ended up finding the problem.  One of the developers made a JS method that would convert our modules on the page to a div structure so he could apply styles too.  This took the modules children via a .html() method and concatenated it onto a string with the new structure.  This of course broke all bindings of that element.  I will end up posting how I debugged this in case other have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple working example:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required.")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "A maximum of 10 characters are allowed")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js") %>"></script>

<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description)%></div>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Description) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

The `MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js` is not included in the standard project template as it is part of the [MVC Futures project](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742#DownloadId=110348) (extract it from the source code).

Once you've put this example into action and proved it to work you could start adding functionality.

Comment: I've tried doing all this.   Our application is to mature now to strip out everything and rebuild it..well by too far it means only as a last resort since it will take a week to do properly.  I'm doing a deep dive into the MS and JQuery js files today.  If that doesn't yield much then we will probably just give up on it since we don't have to time to architect for a feature that really only saves some code/errors in repeating duplicate code.  for the amount of time we have spent on it, we could of wrote all the validation both sides twice.  thanks though.